# CSS Modification with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, lines

I'm able to change the CSS ID of an item with Javascript through a simple code like this:

```
<div id="teststyle1">Test Text, 1-1</div>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('teststyle1').style.color='red'"> Test 1 </button>
```

However, when I try to add in a second line of text (like in the full example below) with the same ID, only one of them gets changed. Is there a simple fix to this issue where both of the items would be changed?

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#teststyle1{
text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="teststyle1">Test Text, 1-1</div>
<div id="teststyle1">Test Text, 1-2</div>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('teststyle1').style.color='red'">Test 1</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: IDs should be unique, maybe go for a approach with using class names? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName - works from IE9+

Comment: Actually, instead of changing styles inline, set another class name, it's much cleaner to have all styles in one place

Comment: Not should, **must** be unique.

Comment: This is really basic. Before starting JavaScript, you might want to get the hang of CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Ids should be unique. You want to use a class instead.

```
<div class="teststyle1">Test Text, 1-1</div>
<div class="teststyle1">Test Text, 1-2</div>

<button type="button" onclick="Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('teststyle1'), function(element) { element.style.color='red'; })"> Test 1 </button>
```

Though for readability and good style, I recommend:

```
<div class="teststyle1">Test Text, 1-1</div>
<div class="teststyle1">Test Text, 1-2</div>

<button id="my_button" type="button"> Test 1 </button>
<script>
    document.getElementById('my_button').onclick = function() {
        Array.prototype.forEach(document.getElementsByClassName('teststyle1'), function(element) {
            element.style.color='red';
        });
    };
</script>
```

Comment: `NodeList` does not inherit the Array prototype, and as such, does not have a `forEach` method. You can make it into an array with `[].slice.call`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use ids on different elements. Try using class and then javascript will change all elements under  the class

Answer (score 0):

id is unique  it's always apply first matching  if you want go for class

```
<div class="class1">Test Text, 1-1</div>
<div class="class1">Test Text, 1-2</div>
```

in jquery you can access  based on index

```
$('.class1:eq(0)').html();
$('.class1:eq(1)').html();
```